# How do I add a new menu item in DAX2012, using the Morph-X IDE?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, dax, morph-x

I have created a submenu and added menu items to it - it show the menu but I cannot get it to show the "Common" area that's on all standard menus.

Can anyone also maybe indicate how I can check the menus' information storage in the database? There may be a corruption of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the 'common' area just a regular sub-menu? For instance, under the 'home' menu, there are sub-menus for 'common', 'inquiries', 'reports', etc.? If you want to see the common area, wouldn't you just create a sub-menu named 'common'?